# How to get the origin IP of a netTcpBinding call in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, ip-address, nettcpbinding

The called method have access to binding-level information like the origin IP address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use this snippet:

```
((RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name]).Address;
```